# Problems storing information of JSON into dictionary for loop in python

Tags: python, json, loops, web

I'm new in this of API's and web development. so I'm sorry if my question is  very basic :(.

I  want to create a web browser of food recipes based in  the ingredients contained. I'm using 2 queries urls to obtain the information because  I need to acces to 2 json files. First one to obtain the id for each recipe based in the ingredient searched by the user and  second one to obtain the information of each recipe based on the id returned in the first url.

The code I have is this one:

```
#Function that return id's of recipes that contains the word queried by user.
def ids(query):
    try:
        api_key  = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/autocomplete?apiKey={api_key}&query={urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)}")
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return response
    try: 
        ids = []
        quotes = response.json()
        for quote in quotes:
            ids.append(quote['id'])
        return ids
    except (KeyError,TypeError, ValueError):
        return None

#save inside a list named "ids", the id's of recipes that contains the ingredient chicken
ids = ids("chicken")

#function that return the differents options of recipes based in the ids.
def lookup(ids):
    for ID in ids:
        try:
            api_key  = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
            response = requests.get(f"https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/{ID}/information?apiKey{api_key}&includeNutrition=false")
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.RequestException:
            return response
```

The main issue I have is that I don't know how to store the information returned in response, as you may notice I use into the "lookup" function a loop to get  the responses for all ID contained in the list ids, but considering that I'll obtain 1 response for each ID (for instance if I have 6 ids, I'll obtain 6 different responses with 6 different information into the json files).

finally the info I want to store is this one

```
quote = response.json()
results = {'id':quote["id"],'title':quote["title"],'url':quote["sourceUrl"]}
```

This is the link with a sample of the data and the url used to obtain the json

https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Recipe-Information

I'm stucking trying to store this information located inside the different json files in a dictionary using python.

Any kind of help will be  amazing!!

Comment: I recommend that lookup() should return a dictionary.  The ids would be the keys of the dictionary.  The values of the dictionary would the the json of the reponse.  I recommend providing sample data as part of your question.  The specific API returning the responses isn't that important.  Sample data and a working example (that does not require private information like API keys) makes it much easier to write answers.

Comment: @AaronBentley I   update the info man :) a sample of the data is into this url https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Recipe-Information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would best use a `dict` for it with a structure matching the recipes you get back:

Assuming the API returns `name`, `duration`, `difficulty` and these are fields you will use later, as well as that you also save other data besides recipes for your program you could use a `dict`. If this is not the case simply use a `list` of `dicts` that represent single recipes

```
#just a dummy setup to simulate getting different recipes back from the API
one_response = {"name" : "Chicken and Egg", "duration" : 14, "difficulty" : "easy"} 
another_response = {"name" : "Chicken square", "duration" : 100, "difficulty" : "hard"} 

def get_recipe(id): 
    if id == 1: 
        return one_response
    else:
        return another_response 

ids = [1,2]
# Here would be other information maybe as well, that you capture somewhere else. If you don't have this then simply use a list with recipes dicts inside..
queried_recipes = {"recipes" :[] }

for i in ids: 
    # Here you simply add a recipes to your recipes dict
    queried _recipes["recipes"].append(get_recipe(i)) 

print (queried_recipes)
OUT: {'recipes': [{'name': 'Chicken and Egg', 'duration': 14, 'difficulty': 'easy'}, {'name': 'Chicken square', 'duration': 100, 'difficulty': 'hard'}]}

print(queried_recipes["recipes"][0]["duration"])
OUT: 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Recipe-Information-Bulk instead.  That will get you all the information you want in one JSON document without having to loop through repeated calls to `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/{ID}/information`.

However, to answer the original question:

```
def lookup(ids):
    api_key  = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
    results = []
    for ID in ids:            
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/{ID}/information?apiKey{api_key}&includeNutrition=false")
        response.raise_for_status()
        quote = response.json()
        result = {'id':quote["id"],'title':quote["title"],'url':quote["sourceUrl"]}
        results.append(result)
    return results
```